# DataTables YADCF Plug In

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I have a DataTable 1.10 which uses the YADCF Plugin, I had some data from a table that loaded in fine, I've now change the table to another table with an identical structure. I am getting the error:

In Chrome :

```
    jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js:2910 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yadcf_data_0' of null(anonymous function) 
@ jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js:2910m.event.dispatch @ datatables.min.js:16r.handle @ datatables.min.js:16m.event.trigger @ datatables.min.js:16(anonymous function) @ datatables.min.js:16m.extend.each @ datatables.min.js:14m.fn.m.each @ datatables.min.js:14m.fn.extend.trigger @ datatables.min.js:16v @ datatables.min.js:134o.error @ datatables.min.js:94j @ datatables.min.js:14k.fireWith @ datatables.min.js:14x @ datatables.min.js:17b @ datatables.min.js:17
    3index.php:601
```

and In FireFox :

```
TypeError: json is null
initAndBindTable/<()
 jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js:2910
m.event.dispatch()
 datatables.min.js:16
m.event.add/r.handle()
 datatables.min.js:16
m.event.trigger()
 datatables.min.js:16
.trigger/<()
 datatables.min.js:16
.each()
 datatables.min.js:14
m.prototype.each()
 datatables.min.js:14
.trigger()
 datatables.min.js:16
v()
 datatables.min.js:134
ra/o.error()
 datatables.min.js:94
m.Callbacks/j()
 datatables.min.js:14
m.Callbacks/k.fireWith()
 datatables.min.js:14
x()
 datatables.min.js:17
.send/b()
 datatables.min.js:17
 jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js:2910:1
```

Does anyone know whats going on here and why the two tables with identical structure just different records are throwing this error?

Comment: Please try the latest yadcf [beta version from github](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) , and let me know what is the error line and even better provide a jsbin sample

Comment: I think, It may be DataTables instead as I comment out the Yadcf code and it throws an error Tech Note 1 for datatables, invalid JSON data